# Powershell script to call git init in all subdirectories

Tags: windows, git, powershell, directory

I want to init repositories in all subdirectories in a given directory. Since there are about 200 of them (legacy projects), I want to automate it with Powershell. So far I have:

```
 $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "."

    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
          if ($item.Attributes -eq "Directory")
          {
              $git = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git"
              & $git "init"
          }
    }
```

Obviously I am missing a line where I make use of each subdirectory in the loop. In its current form, I believe all this does it call "git init" over and over in the same directory ("."), so what is the way to call git init from inside of each of the subdirectories? Is there a way to temporarily "cd" into each subdirectory found?

I tried something naive like

```
& $item.Name + "\git init"
```

But it doesn't like that, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cmdlets you are looking for are `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`. The former will change the current working directory to whatever argument you pass to it. The old location will be stored on a stack. Once you have changed the directory using `Push-Location`, you can execute commands locally as if you manually cd’d into them. Afterwards, call `Pop-Location` to clear the stack and go back to the original directory.

Btw. note that checking `Attributes` equality for `"Directory"` will not necessarily be good enough to identify directories. While you can be sure that you will *only* find directories using that, there may be other directories which have other attribute flags set as well. See also the [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enumeration.

A better way to check for directories is to check the `PSIsContainer` property. It will simply be true for directories, and otherwise false.

Using PowerShell’s piping, you can also write this all in a single line:

```
Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { Push-Location $_.FullName; git init; Pop-Location }
```

This will first get all items in the current directory and push them into the pipe. Then they will be filtered for directories (`?` is filter), and then commands will be executed for each item that is left in the pipe (`%` is for each). So you call `Push-Location` to get to the directory’s location, call `git init` there, and then go back using `Pop-Location`.

*Note:* If you are using PowerShell 3, you can also use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` to filter for directories right away.

Comment: So I'm a total Powershell noob, so if I just use Push-Location within my example script's loop above and then Pop-Location after I do my necessary commands, would that do the same thing? This is a nice one-liner but a bit harder to read for me.

Comment: both answers look good, but this one worked out for me by just modifying my current script. Thank you

Comment: One last question about the directory checking: If I were to do it the "simple" way as in my example, could I just put this in the if statement instead of what I have now? "if ($item.PSIsContainer)" (I looked up and understand the meaning of "$_" now though.)

Comment: Yes, that will also work. The `$_` variable is just the current item of the foreach loop. So it’s the same as using `$item` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is call this command:

```
gci c:\parent\folder | ? { $_.PSIsContainer; } | % { cd $_.FullName; git init; };
```

1. The first bit is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, which gets a list of subdirectories and files of the "parent folder." It passes those items onto the next command via the `pipe` character `|`
2. The `PSIsContainer` bit filters the list of "child items" for folders only, so as to exclude files. It passes these folders onto the next command via the pipe `|`
3. The final bit is an alias for `ForEach-Object`, which performs a series of tasks for each object in the PowerShell pipeline.

   - Set the current location to the folder path
   - Call `git init`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Push-Pull Location, you might use simpler version of poke's script

```
Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { git -C $_.FullName pull }
```